# Segmentation fault while reading file/input with getline

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, getline

I am trying to develop a simple 3d-model viewer, which should be able to read files line by line in the obj format. This seemed to be very simple, however when `std::getline` hits `eof`, the program exits with a segmentation fault.

Here, I've made the smallest amount of code which gives me a segfault (I use `std::cin` here, so that my program doesn't end immediately, but I actually get a chance to input some stuff into it, and manually enter an eof):

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::cout<<line;
    }
```

Another thing to notice is, that this code will only produce a segfault if the line containing eof is empty, otherwise, if eof is entered on a line containing anything else, the loop simply carries on.

Edit:
Now, I've reproduced this with the smallest code possible:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Model.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::string path = "/home/thor/Skrivebord/3d_files/Exported.obj";
    obj::Model(path.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

**Model.h**

```
#ifndef MODEL_H_INCLUDED
#define MODEL_H_INCLUDED

namespace obj
{
    class Model
    {
    public:
        Model(const char* path);
    };
}

#endif // MODEL_H_INCLUDED
```

**Model.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

namespace obj
{
    class Model
    {
    public:
        Model(const char* path);

    private:
        std::string name = ""; // Remove this line, and all works.
    };

    Model::Model(const char* path)
    {
        std::string line;

        while(std::getline(std::cin, line))
        {
            std::cout << line;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just do `while (getline(cin, line))` without the conditional `eof()`.

Comment: I have already tried that, and it still gives me a segfault.

Comment: Then show us your actual code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the two lines of code posted. Whatever your problem is it's in the code you didn't post.

Comment: There's happy medium between posting almost no code, and posting all your code. Start removing things from your code, make the program smaller and smaller, while still having the error you are asking about. When the program is as small as you can make it but still has the error, post all of that code.

Comment: Something seriously wrong here. I can't test your exact code because I don't have C++11. But no way should that crash as you say it does. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using gcc 4.8 on Ubuntu 12.04. And I can't see any part of the code that uses C++11.

Comment: `std::string name = ""` is only legal in C++11. I tested it without `= ""` and it didn't crash for me (no surprise).

Comment: Now I tested it without the `= ""` as well, and it still gives segfault.

Comment: @Lillesort131 OK now I see it, I was blind. I'll answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code has two conflicting declarations of `Model`.

In Model.cpp you have

```
class Model
{
public:
    Model(const char* path);

private:
    std::string name = ""; // Remove this line, and all works.
};
```

but in Model.h you have

```
class Model
{
public:
    Model(const char* path);
};
```

You should have one definition of `Model` only, put that in Model.h and `#include "Model.h"` in Model.cpp

Comment: Exactly what parts of the code do I need to move? If I just move the class itself, `Model::Model(const char* path){ ... }` gives me an error.

Comment: Just move the class itself **and** add `#include "Model.h"` to Model.cpp.

Comment: You should only have one definition of any class. Put that definition in  a header file and #include the header file anywhere that you need it. That's the technique for making sure that you have consistent class definitions thoughout your code.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. I simply forgot to `#include "Model.h`.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an error although the logic is hard to follow.

```
void Face::AddVertex(float x, float y, float z)
{
    if (vCnt > 3)
    {
        vertices[vCnt].SetPos(x, y, z);
        ++vCnt;
    }
    else
    {
        vertices.push_back(Vertex(x, y, z));
        ++vCnt;
    }
}
```

It's more logical with `<` not `>` since your `vertices` vector is initially size 3

```
void Face::AddVertex(float x, float y, float z)
{
    if (vCnt < 3)
    {
        vertices[vCnt].SetPos(x, y, z);
        ++vCnt;
    }
    else
    {
        vertices.push_back(Vertex(x, y, z));
        ++vCnt;
    }
}
```